# How to solve tornado memory leak?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, tornado

I ran the tornado as the HTTPServer, and found lots of garbages in gc.garbage, but have no idea about how to clear and avoid  memory leak ? 
Thanks for your help.

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/webapi/", MainHandler, dict(db=db_conn)),
    (r"/web/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path":os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/web'}),
])

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, xheaders=True)
http_server.bind(options.port, options.host)
http_server.start(options.processes)

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Here is the garbage output codes:

```
for x in gc.garbage:
    s = str(x)
    if len(s) > 80: print s[:77] + "..."
    print type(x), "\n  ", s
```

Tornado gc.garbage ouput as below:

```
Garbage Objects:
<class 'tornado.iostream.IOStream'> 
<tornado.iostream.IOStream object at 0x7f05fdcf1550>
{'_write_buffer': None, '_write_buffer_size': 0, '_write_future':None, '_pen...
<type 'dict'> 
{'_write_buffer': None, '_write_buffer_size': 0, '_write_future': None, '_pending_callbacks': 0, '_read_bytes': None, '_closed': True, '_write_callback': None, '_state': None, '_close_callback': None, '_ssl_connect_future': None, 'max_buffer_size': 104857600, 'io_loop':     <tornado.platform.epoll.EPollIOLoop object at 0x7f05fae4eed0>, '_read_until_close': False, '_read_regex': <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f05fc92cc68>, '_write_buffer_frozen': False, '_read_partial': False, '_connect_future': None, 'max_write_buffer_size': None, '_read_callback': None, '_connect_callback': None, 'read_chunk_size': 65536, '_read_future': None, '_read_buffer_size': 0, 'socket': None, '_connecting': False, '_read_max_bytes': 65536, '_streaming_callback': None, 'error': None, '_read_delimiter': None, '_read_buffer': deque([])}
<type 'collections.deque'> 
deque([])
<class 'tornado.httpserver._HTTPRequestContext'> 
127.0.0.1
<class 'tornado.http1connection.HTTP1ServerConnection'> 
<tornado.http1connection.HTTP1ServerConnection object at 0x7f05fae6a0d0>
{'_serving_future': <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x7f05fae6a110>, 'pa...
<type 'dict'> 
{'_serving_future': <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x7f05fae6a110>, 'params':    <tornado.http1connection.HTTP1ConnectionParameters object at 0x7f05fae4ee50>, 'context': <tornado.httpserver._HTTPRequestContext object at 0x7f05fae6a090>, 'stream': <tornado.iostream.IOStream object at  0x7f05fdcf1550>}
... ...
```

Comment: Perhaps the garbage collector hasn't gotten around to cleaning it? Not sure on the full implementation of the garbage collector in Python, but maybe you should add a pause and check again in a minute or two and see if the same objects (i.e, print the `id`s as well) are still there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried as you said, the same objects (i.e, print the ids as well) are still there, will deep to the implementation of  tornado, ps: my tornado version is 4.3.